# Different slices give different inequalities for same elements

Tags: python, numpy, precision

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([.4], dtype='float32')
b = np.array([.4, .6])

print(a > b)
print(a > b[0], a > b[1])
print(a[0] > b[0], a[0] > b[1])
```

```py
[ True False]
[False] [False]
True False
```

What's the deal? Yes, `b.dtype == 'float64'`, but so are its slices `b[0]` & `b[1]`, and `a` remains `'float32'`.

*Note*: I'm asking *why* this occurs, not how to circumvent it, which I know (e.g. cast both to `'float64'`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've noted [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58558241/5067311), type casting in numpy is pretty complicated, and this is the root cause of the behaviour you are seeing. The documents linked in that answer make it clear that scalars(/0d arrays) and 1d arrays differ in type conversions, since the latter aren't considered value by value.

The first half of the problem you already know: the problem is that type conversion happens differently for your two cases:

```py
>>> (a + b).dtype
dtype('float64')

>>> (a + b[0]).dtype
dtype('float32')

>>> (a[0] + b[0]).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

There's also a helper called [`numpy.result_type()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html) that can tell you the same information without having to perform the binary operation:

```py
>>> np.result_type(a, b)
dtype('float64')
>>> np.result_type(a, b[0])
dtype('float32')
>>> np.result_type(a[0], b[0])
dtype('float64')
```

I believe we can understand what's happening in your example if we consider the type conversion tables:

```
>>> from numpy.testing import print_coercion_tables
can cast
[...]

In these tables, ValueError is '!', OverflowError is '@', TypeError is '#'

scalar + scalar
+ ? b h i l q p B H I L Q P e f d g F D G S U V O M m 
? ? b h i l q l B H I L Q L e f d g F D G # # # O ! m 
b b b h i l q l h i l d d d e f d g F D G # # # O ! m 
h h h h i l q l h i l d d d f f d g F D G # # # O ! m 
i i i i i l q l i i l d d d d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
l l l l l l q l l l l d d d d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
q q q q q q q q q q q d d d d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
p l l l l l q l l l l d d d d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
B B h h i l q l B H I L Q L e f d g F D G # # # O ! m 
H H i i i l q l H H I L Q L f f d g F D G # # # O ! m 
I I l l l l q l I I I L Q L d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
L L d d d d d d L L L L Q L d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
Q Q d d d d d d Q Q Q Q Q Q d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
P L d d d d d d L L L L Q L d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
e e e f d d d d e f d d d d e f d g F D G # # # O ! # 
f f f f d d d d f f d d d d f f d g F D G # # # O ! # 
d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d g D D G # # # O ! # 
g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g G G G # # # O ! # 
F F F F D D D D F F D D D D F F D G F D G # # # O ! # 
D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D G D D G # # # O ! # 
G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G # # # O ! # 
S # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # O ! # 
U # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # O ! # 
V # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # O ! # 
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O ! # 
M ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! 
m m m m m m m m m m m m m m # # # # # # # # # # # ! m 

scalar + neg scalar
[...]

array + scalar
+ ? b h i l q p B H I L Q P e f d g F D G S U V O M m 
? ? b h i l q l B H I L Q L e f d g F D G # # # O ! m 
b b b b b b b b b b b b b b e f d g F D G # # # O ! m 
h h h h h h h h h h h h h h f f d g F D G # # # O ! m 
i i i i i i i i i i i i i i d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
l l l l l l l l l l l l l l d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
q q q q q q q q q q q q q q d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
p l l l l l l l l l l l l l d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
B B B B B B B B B B B B B B e f d g F D G # # # O ! m 
H H H H H H H H H H H H H H f f d g F D G # # # O ! m 
I I I I I I I I I I I I I I d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
L L L L L L L L L L L L L L d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
P L L L L L L L L L L L L L d d d g D D G # # # O ! m 
e e e e e e e e e e e e e e e e e e F F F # # # O ! # 
f f f f f f f f f f f f f f f f f f F F F # # # O ! # 
d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d D D D # # # O ! # 
g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g G G G # # # O ! # 
F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F # # # O ! # 
D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D # # # O ! # 
G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G G # # # O ! # 
S # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # O ! # 
U # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # O ! # 
V # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # O ! # 
O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O ! # 
M ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! 
m m m m m m m m m m m m m m # # # # # # # # # # # ! m

[...]
```

The above is part of the current promotion tables for value-based promotion. It denotes how differing types contribute to a result type when pairing two numpy objects of a given kind (see the first column and first row for the specific types). The types are to be understood according to the [single-character dtype specifications](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#index-6) (below "One-character strings"), in particular `np.dtype('f')` corresponds to `np.float32` (f for C-style float) and `np.dtype('d')` (d for C-style double) to `np.float64` (see also `np.typename('f')` and the same for `'d'`).

I have noted two items in boldface in the above tables:

> scalar f + scalar d --> d
> array f + scalar d --> f

Now let's look at your cases. The premise is that you have an `'f'` array `a` and a `'d'` array `b`. The fact that `a` only has a single element doesn't matter: it's a 1d array with length 1 rather than a 0d array.

1. When you do `a > b` you are comparing two arrays, this is not denoted in the above tables. I'm not sure what the behaviour is here; my guess is that `a` gets broadcast to `b`'s shape and then its type is cast to `'d'`. The reason I think this is that `np.can_cast(a, np.float64)` is `True` and `np.can_cast(b, np.float32)` is `False`. But this is just a guess, a lot of this machinery in numpy is not intuitive to me.
2. When you do `a > b[0]` you are comparing a `'f'` array to a `'d'` scalar, so according to the above you get a `'f'` array. That's what `(a + b[0]).dtype` told us. (When you use `a > b[0]` you don't see the conversion step, because the result is always a bool.)
3. When you do `a[0] > b[0]` you are comparing a `'f'` scalar to a `'d'` scalar, so according to the above you get a `'d'` scalar. That's what `(a[0] + b[0]).dtype` told us.

So I believe this is all consistent with the quirks of type conversion in numpy. While it might seem like an unfortunate corner case with the value of `0.4` in double and single precision, this feature goes deeper and the problem serves as a big red warning that you should be very careful when mixing different dtypes.

The safest course of action is to convert your types yourself in order to control what happens in your code. Especially since there's discussion about reconsidering some aspects of type promotion.

---

As a side note (for now), there's a work-in-progress [NEP 50](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0050-scalar-promotion.html) created in May 2021 that explains how confusing type promotion can be when scalars are involved, and plans to simplify some of the rules eventually. Since this also involves breaking changes, its implementation in NumPy proper won't happen overnight.

Comment: Nice research! I did manage to confuse myself on my (now deleted) answer. I se you got to your laptop. No Pythonista on your phone? ;) Best app I ever installed!

Comment: @Ethan thanks :) A few years ago I looked into python apps but I've found only one and that one wanted dubious permissions. I'm certain it wasn't Pythonista, so I'll look into that, thanks!

Comment: Excellent, thank you. A clarification before accepting: what do `'f'` and `'d'` stand for? Linked reading will suffice - also on how to interpret the `print_coercion_tables` output (looks just like random letters to me).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon thanks for the formatting fix! Sorry, I meant to add those character specifications but I forgot; please see my update under the tables.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Perfect

Comment: I think the link to [NEP 50](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0050-scalar-promotion.html) is valuable here. I hope this all becomes less complicated in a future NumPy version.

Comment: @CrisLuengo good idea, I've added it along with `np.result_type`, thanks. In my defense the NEP came out more than a year after I wrote this answer ;)

Comment: Hey, you gave me that link, I don't know what you're defending against. I just wanted to point out that things might change in the future. I sooo hope that your answer here becomes obsolete! ;)